# telescope as homotopy pushout

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've stumbled upon the following which I can not prove.

> For topological spaces, the telescope 
>   $$hocolim(X_0 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow ...)$$
>   is homotopic to 
>   $$ hocolim(\bigvee X_i \stackrel{id \vee id}{\leftarrow} \bigvee X_i \vee \bigvee X_i \stackrel{id\vee \bigvee f_i}{\rightarrow} \bigvee X_i \vee \bigvee X_i)  $$

If we were simply dealing with colimits, I think I would simply show that it satisfies the universal property. However, I am not sure how to tackle the problem when dealing with homotopy colimits.

Comment: Homotopy colimits also satisfy a universal property, although I can't say if it would be much help here